# Difference between vector.back() and vector[vector.size() - 1]?

Tags: c++, vector

Is there any difference between calling `vector.back()` and `vector[vector.size() - 1]` with `std::vector`'s?

Comment: Readability springs to mind as a major difference

Comment: The case where the vector is empty also springs to mind.

Comment: When the vector is empty, *both* will cause undefined behaviour.

Comment: In addition to other answers, back is present in other standard containers that are not random access, like a list. Using it will help make your code container type agnostic.

Comment: @Steve Good point. I added that to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`vector.back()` is simpler to read and write. Also, more containers offer `c.back()` than `c[c.size() - 1]`, which is important for generic code.

In a debug-runtime, both are equally likely to be trapped on empty containers, nor is the resulting code and thus their performance when using optimization expected to differ significantly.

Answer (score 2):

`vector.back()` is one function call and shorter to write: It is simpler. `vector[vector.size() - 1]` is two function calls and a subtraction, and longer to write: It is more complex.

Behaviourally, they are the same for `std::vector`. However `back` is more generic, and can be used with all standard bidirectional containers (`std::forward_list` being the only standard container that doesn't support it). `operator[]` is only supported by random access containers.

Comment: Wonder why count function calls... That say nothing about performance but seems to  be related to that...

Comment: @Jarod42 There was no question about performance. There was a question about difference. Number of operations differ, and that affects complexity, which affects readability if not performance.

Comment: @Jarod42 I don't understand, of course it does not affect performance here, but if I'm not mistaken, function calls have a cost, so theoretically, I would say the more function calls we have, the more it will reduce performance. Am I wrong ?

Comment: @Fareanor: `back()` might be internally implemented with the other, (making `back` less performant). I think the count as misleading as readers might read it as performance concern, and not, as expected by the answer, the "difficulty" to read. (I avoid *"complexity"* word which has same issue IMO).

Comment: @Jarod42 Oh right, I didn't see these concerns by reading your first comment. Thank you for the clarification :)